# jQuery find element: please help make this span ('bar') red (jsfiddle)

Tags: jquery

Newbie here, I have this html

```
<p>
    <div id="divTest">foo</div>
</p>
<p>
    <span>bar</span> 
    <span>bar</span><!-- make this 'bar' red -->
</p>
```

And I can't find a way to select the second  when starting from div#divTest

Tried this
`$("#divTest").parent().next('p').children('span:nth-child(1)').css("color","red");`  but didn't work

Please help

jsfiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/Vc36P/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $("#divTest").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('span').eq(1).css('color','red')
    }); 
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Vc36P/5/).

You've got the problem that a `div` cannot be contained within a `p` element, that's invalid HTML; therefore the browser, when constructing the DOM, will (unpredictably) move the `div` outside of the `p` (though it's not clear, beforehand, where to). You need to construct valid HTML first:

```
<div id="divTest">foo</div>
<p>
    <span>bar</span> 
    <span>bar</span><!-- make this 'bar' red -->
</p>
```

Which allows for:

```
$(function(){
    $("#divTest").click(function(){
        $(this).next('p').find('span').eq(1).css('color','red')
    }); 
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Vc36P/8/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).

Comment: Thanks David! It works perfectly! I was scratching my head for few hours trying to make it red.

Comment: You're welcome; basically, though, if something in JavaScript doesn't work first check the error console for anything obvious, then check to make sure you're using the methods appropriately and *then* make sure the HTML is actually valid (and used in a valid way). But I'm glad to have been of help, and thank *you* for the accept! :D

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'm a designer learning to code actually. This stackoverflow community rocks! You guys reply incredibly fast. :D

Answer (score 0):

Hi i did this hope it helps ..http://jsfiddle.net/Vc36P/6/

```
$(function(){
    var a = $("p span").eq(1).css('color','red'); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct html syntax, because it is impossible to place a `<div>` element inside a `<p>` in the DOM because the opening  tag will automatically close the `<p>` element.

`<p><div></div></p>` is not valid HTML and the browser is well within its rights to attempt to correct it by closing the `<p>` before the `<div>`:

```
<p></p><div></div><p></p>
```

You can't put a `<div>` inside a `<p>` and get consistent results from various browsers. Provide the browsers with valid HTML and they will behave better.

You can put `<div>` inside a `<div>` though so if you replace your `<p>` with `<div class="p">` and style it appropriately, you can get what you want.

See, for example, http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html. It specifies which elements are block elements and which are inline. For those lists, search for the section marked "HTML content models".

For the P element, it specifies the following, which indicates that P elements are only allowed to contain inline elements.

```
<!ELEMENT P - O (%inline;)*            -- paragraph -->
```

This is consistent with http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1, which says that the P element "cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself)."

Comment: Thanks Ishan for your helpful explanation. I've learned a lot today. At least from my web design view, I never knew that <p> cannot contain <p>!

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to mark your spans or p-container with some class or id:

```
<p>
    <div id="divTest">foo</div>
</p>
<p class="colors">
    <span class="blue">bar</span> 
    <span class="red">bar</span><!-- make this 'bar' red -->
</p>
```

and find it by this classname or id:

```
$(function(){
    $(".colors .red").css({'color': 'red'}); 
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vc36P/13/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I realized later on that my problem was about how to get out of the parent and target adjacent parent's second child. Now I use David's solution and added classname to second span (no need to eq(1)) as your suggestion. Working now :D